# Computing the stabilizer of any polynomial of degree $n$ with distinct roots.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, geometric-invariant-theory, orbit-stabilizer, stabilizer

How to compute the stabilizer of any polynomial of degree $n$ with distinct roots? I was told in case of polynomials of degree 3 in 2 variables this is related to the fact that there is a unique automorphism of $\mathbb P^1$ that fixes three points.

Any helful hints of calculating the stabilizer say of p(x) = $x^2y^5 + xy$? I am using the $n^{th}$ inverse of the determinant as a character, where $n$ is the degree of the polynomial.

Comment: With respect to what action, and what do you mean by "distinct roots" in the multivariate case? Are you referring to the action of the general linear group?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan yes the action of the GL(n).